# how does execfile() work in python?

Tags: python

does the file which is sent as an argument to execfile runs as an independent process / thread or is the code imported and then executed ? . Also i wanted to know how efficient is it compared to running threads / process .

Comment: "compared to running threads / process".  It can't be compared.  Why do you ask?

Comment: well i didnt know , it cant be compared . the reason i asked was to know how actually it works , since i come from c/c++ background i thought this would work similar to inline function concept or so , which i m unsure of.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The file is not run in a separate thread or process, it runs synchronously with the caller.

Comment: well can u elaborate a bit on that .  Is it that the code in the file is imported via execfile() and after execution the the next instruction in the parent file is executed ?

Comment: yes, exactly.  You might try experimenting with it to see how it behaves for your application.

Comment: "try experimenting".  Good suggestion.